# Saving inserted value into c# variable

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, scope

I want to update my `stock.quantity` attribute by adding it with the last inserted value. But I am getting error `Use of unassigned local variable 'qty'` in the if block. I cannot initialize it to 0, because every time when `manageStock` is called it will get initialized to 0.

this is my code

```
public static void manageStock(CompanyStock stock)
        {
            ///// Check if record exists/////////

            cmd = new SqlCommand("select count(*) from tblStock where prodName=@prodName", con);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prodName", stock.prodName);
            int count;
            int qty;
            try
            {
                con.Open();
                count = (Int32)cmd.ExecuteScalar(); //returns null if doesnt exist
            }

            finally {
                con.Close();
            }


            if (count > 0)
            {

                stock.quantity += qty;
                cmd = new SqlCommand("update tblStock set quantity = @quantity where prodName=@prodName", con);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prodName", stock.prodName);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@quantity", stock.quantity);

            }
            else
            {
                qty = stock.quantity;
                cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into tblStock(prodName,quantity) values (@prodName, @quantity)", con);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prodName",stock.prodName);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@quantity",stock.quantity);


            }


            try
            {
                con.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            }

            finally
            {
                con.Close();
            }


        }


    }
```

Please tell me how can I achieve this?

Comment: Have you tried "ExecuteScalar"?

Comment: How? can u please elaborate?

Comment: A quick google search for "ExecuteScalar C#" gives me this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks sir! and sorry if my question was stupid

Comment: It's not. None of this is magic.  It took me a while to realize that all of this is discoverable.

Comment: you are using a static method, and this variable quantity needs to keep its value. You already know that it has to be initialized. So I think you are obligated to put it outside your method. Because it's a static method, you'll also need to make it a static variable. So you need to place `static int qty = 0;` outside your method.